# How to merge multiple dataframe columns into one?

Tags: r, merge, rowsum

I have a dataframe with 21 columns. I want to merge 15 of these columns into one that can be identified as a variable 'Other.' This is my code so far, and I am not having luck in doing this so far, with rowSums it says

```
Error in as.data.frame(y) : argument "y" is missing, with no default
```

And I don't know what else to try.

```
#Read in group abundances
 group.raw <- read.table("taxa_levels/phylum.txt", header=T, row.names=1, sep = "\t")
 group <- t(group)
 group <- sweep(group, 1, rowSums(group), '/') #Calculate relative abundance 
 group$Other <- rowSums(c("p__1", "p__2", "p__5", "p__6", "p__7", "p__8", "p__11", "p__12", "p__13", "p__14", "p__16", "p__17", "p__18", "p__19", "p__20"))
```

The data 'group' looks like this:

```
  row.names     p__1            p__2    
  1 X30841102   3.369851e-06    0.000000e+00    
  2 X49812105   0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00

 > str(group)
  num [1:152, 1:21] 3.37e-06 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 ...
  - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:152] "X30841102" "X49812105" "X26402102" "X25951102" ...
  ..$ : chr [1:21] "p__1" "p__2" "p__3" "p__4" ...
```

Comment: You are trying to `rowSums` across a vector of names. You need to do `rowSums(group[c("p__1","p__2")])` instead.

Comment: @thelatemail I tried that, and it gives this error now: 'Error in rowSums(phyla[c("p__1", "p__2", "p__5",  : 
  'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions'

Comment: You might have a matrix - therefore `rowSums(group[,c("p__1","p__2")])` - note the added comma to select columns.

Comment: can we see information on `str(group)` from just before you try the `rowSums()` command?

Comment: @thelatemail Yes it is a matrix. Trying that gives: 'Error in phyla[, c("p__1", "p__2", "p__5",  : 
  subscript out of bounds'

Comment: @BenBolker: Here is it:  '> str(group)
 num [1:152, 1:21] 3.37e-06 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:152] "X30841102" "X49812105" "X26402102" "X25951102" ...
  ..$ : chr [1:21] "p__1" "p__2" "p__3" "p__4" ...' Also added it to the question.

Comment: No idea then. Using `group <- structure(c(3.37e-06, 0, 0, 0), .Dim = c(2L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("X30841102", "X49812105"), c("p__1", "p__2")))` which matches what you present exactly, the `rowSums(group[,c("p__1","p__2")])` code works fine.

Comment: That excerpt of `group`, is it before or after you transposed it?

Comment: It was before. I have fixed it now, thanks!